# `auto-increment` std::map<string, int> :)

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary, auto-increment

Ok, the problem is pretty straightforward - I am reading words from the input stream, the words may repeat. I need to populate a map so that all the words get indices from 0 to n-1.
Here is my code:

```
map<string, int> mp;
string s;
int n = 0;
while(cin >> s)
{
   if(mp.find(s) == mp.end())
   {
      mp.insert(make_pair(s, n++));
   }
}
```

Is this the best way to achieve what I want to achieve or are there more elegant, more STL-ish solutions? Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you need an index? Are you using this to map a word to an index into a vector where you store more information in the vector. Why not just store the information in the map?

Comment: @Martin: Eventually I am going to construct an adjacency matrix for a graph whose vertices are these strings. using indexes as graph vertices is convenient

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need to check whether there is an element at that key before you insert because `insert` doesn't change the mapped value if the key already exists.  You don't need to keep track of the count separately; you can just call `size()` to get the next value:

```
while (std::cin >> s)
{
    mp.insert(std::make_pair(s, mp.size()));
}
```